# VS2017 building app shows error LNK1181 cannot open input file 'C:\instantclient_19_3\sdk\lib\msvc\oraocci19d.lib

Tags: c++, mfc, instantclient

I am using VS 2017 for a legacy MFC app.

I have Oracle 19.13.0 installed and I downloaded **intantclient_19_18** SDK Package (instantclient-sdk-windows.x64-19.18.0.0.0dbru.zip from https://www.oracle.com/ca-fr/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html) and unzipped in my C: folder, so I have it installed in my C drive like:

C:\instantclient_19_18.

Then I went to `Project`->`Properties`->`Configuration Properties`->`C/C++`->`Additional Include Directories` and add path to my **C:\instantclient_19_18\sdk\include** folder

[image]

I also went to `Project`->`Properties`->`Configuration Properties`->`Linker`->`General`->`Additional Library Directories` and add path to my **C:\instantclient_19_18\sdk\lib\msvc** to tell the linker where to find Oracle libraries.

[image]

If I build my project now, I am getting error:

**LNK1181   cannot open input file 'C:\instantclient_19_3\sdk\lib\msvc\oraocci19d.lib**

I am just starting to work in C++ and would appreciate help to resolve this error.  Thank you.

Comment: ***LNK1181 cannot open input file 'C:\instantclient_19_3\sdk\lib\msvc\oraocci19d.lib*** Usually means 1 or more of the following: 1) The path or file name is incorrect, 2) You are mixing 32 and 64 bit, or 3) The file is corrupt. My expectation is #2 the lib you are using is x64 and not 32 bit.

Comment: I donwloaded 32 bit version of instantclient_19_18 as you suggested but I am still getting the same error.  I just noticed then that the error actually complains about different version (19_3) so it is the versioning issue most likely.  I am not sure where is it getting this 19_3 version from, I checked all project>properties and did not find any though.

Comment: May have to do a clean build and possibly delete any generated precompiled headers. Sometimes I delete the entire Debug and Release folders.

Comment: actually I found it.  it was still referencing the 19_3 version in project > properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies.  Once I change the version to my version of instantclient (19.18), now I can build project.  Thank you so much

Comment: @drescherjm mind providing your comments as answer and I will accept it.  Much appreciated again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error:

> LNK1181 cannot open input file 'C:\instantclient_19_3\sdk\lib\msvc\oraocci19d.lib

usually means 1 or more of the following: 1) The path or file name is incorrect, 2) You are mixing 32 and 64 bit, or 3) The file is corrupt.

From the naming of the download I expect that you are installing a 64 bit binary while your IDE shows you are building a 32 bit application. You need a 32 bit compiled library you can not mix and match.

Comment: Thank you, that helped.  In addition, I had to ensure that correct version of instantclient is referenced in in project > properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies